# $\frac{a+b}{c+b}=\frac{c+d}{a+d}\Rightarrow a=c$ or $a+b+c+d=0$

Tags: calculus

Please find my mistake or give hint:

If $\frac{c}{a}\geq 1$, then by mediant inequality:

$1\leq\frac{a+b}{c+b}$ and $\frac{c+d}{a+d}\leq 1\Rightarrow c=a$

If $\frac{a}{c}\geq 1$, then:

$\frac{a+b}{c+b}\leq 1$ and $1\leq \frac{c+d}{a+d}\Rightarrow c=a$

thnks

Comment: Your two cases don't cover all the possibilities.

Comment: 1st Mistake: if $c/a \ge 1$ then $c \ge a$ which implies that $\frac{a+b}{c+b}\le 1$ and not $\ge1$ as you have it. 2nd mistake you infer that c=a because $\frac{a+b}{c+b}\ge 1$ and $\frac{a+d}{c+d}\le 1$ but $b$ and $d$ can be different.

Comment: Hint: Subtract 1 from both sides

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
\frac{a+b}{c+b}  = \frac{c+d}{a+d} \implies
(a+d)(a+b) = (c+d)(c+b)\implies\\
a^2 + ab + ad + db = c^2 + cb + cd + db \implies\\
a^2 - c^2 +ab - cb + ad - cd = 0 \implies\\
(a-c)(a+c) + (a-c)b + (a-c)d = 0 \implies\\
(a-c)(a+b+c+d) = 0
$$